# Правильная реализация экспорта класса из DLL на C++

Tags: c++, классы, visual-c++, dll

Пишу на VC++ 2010. Планирую реализовать плагины в виде Dll, в которых будет класс, перегружающий виртуальные методы базового класса. Хочется написать библиотеку с классом, использование которой не будет зависеть от версии компилятора. Погуглил, понял что просто так экспортировать класс не получится. 
В связи с этим возникли несколько вопросов:

1. Как правильно реализовать экспорт класса из Dll, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было использовать эту библиотеку с другим компилятором (например в Delphi, ну или хотя бы в другой версии Visual Studio)?
2. Какие ограничения будут для такого класса?
3. Можно ли будет связывать такую dll неявно (на одном из сайтов прочитал, что dll экспортирующие классы невозможно загрузить явно с помощью LoadLibrary)?
4. Имеет ли смысл такая реализации плагина, или же лучше писать простые dll с экспортом функций?

Если не сложно, прошу показать какой-нибудь примитивный пример экспорта следующего класса:

```
class Sample {
private:
  int field;
public:
  Sample(const int number)
  {
    field = number;
  }

  ~Sample() {}

  virtual int GetField()
  {
    return field;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Под форточкой экспорт класса - это COM API, Он же ActiveX. Жутко монструозная вещь, но она действительно позволит в дальнейшем использовать ваш класс во всех языках с поддержкой COM.
2. Главное ограничение - С++ не имеет стабильного ABI. Отсюда следует, например, что если в `DLL` выделяется память, освобождать ее нужно в той же самой `DLL`, иначе - рантаймы подерутся и будут жуткие глюки. Просовывание исключений между DLL - отдельный интересный процесс.
3. DLL "с классами" можно связывать с другим бинарником только явно. Тогда вся забота о связывании ложится на компилятор. При этом, и DLL, и то, куда ее привязывают, должны быть собраны одной и той же версией компилятора с одинаковыми настройками - иначе - возможны глюки. (Например, если программу собрали с динамическим включением рантайма, а DLL - со статическим).
4. Пишите экспорт функций или возьмите технологию плагинов, которую уже кто-то сделал - Qt или COM, например. В противном случае, придется вам зубрить MSDN.

Comment: Спасибо! Пойду читать про ActiveX.